# when i call post api in ionic 2 I get Connection refused (x192)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I think I'm writing some mistake in my code I was struggling last 2 days I haven't found a solution please help...

1. error is:-

   ```
   [Error] WebSocket network error: The operation couldn’t be completed. Connection refused (x192)
   [Error] ERROR – Response {_body: XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent, status: 0, ok: false, …}
   Response {_body: XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent, status: 0, ok: false, statusText: “”, headers: Headers, …}Response
   ```
2. and my code is :-

   ```
   import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from ‘@angular/http’;
   import { Injectable } from ‘@angular/core’;
   import ‘rxjs/add/operator/map’;

   /*
   Generated class for the RestapiServiceProvider provider.

   See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection for more info on providers
     and Angular DI.
   */

   @Injectable()
   export class RestapiServiceProvider {

       apiUrl = ‘http://localhost:8100/development/abc/public/api/v1/apiName’;

       constructor(public http: Http) {
           console.log(‘Hello RestapiServiceProvider Provider’);
       }

       getUsers() {

           let headers = new Headers();
           headers.append(‘Content-Type’, ‘application/json’);
           headers.append(‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’, ‘*’);
           headers.append(‘Access-Control-Allow-Methods’, ‘POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT’);
           headers.append(‘Accept’,‘application/json’);
           headers.append(“Access-Control-Allow-Headers”, “X-Requested-With”);

           let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers,withCredentials: true });

           let data1 = JSON.stringify({
                           user_id: 14,
                           token: “dsfdsffsfsffsdfffsdffsfs”
                       });

           if (this.data) {
               return Promise.resolve(this.data);
           }

           return new Promise(resolve => {

               // app.post(’/’, function(req, res, next) {
               // Handle the post for this route
           // })
           this.http.post(this.apiUrl, data1, options)
               .map(res => res.json())
               .subscribe(data => {
                   this.data = data;
                   resolve(this.data);
               });
           });
       }

   }
   ```

Comment: This problem is occurring on your device or chrome?

Comment: The problem is not in your code I think. Its your internet connection that is not allowing you to connect,

Comment: @yash_DedSec Sir i have check already not a internet issue accur... i have add config.ionic.json file its right way or not........... {
  "name": "Demo",
  "app_id": "",
  "type": "ionic-angular",
  "integrations": {
    "cordova": {}
  },
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/pqr",
      "proxyUrl": "http://testsite4me.com/development/abc/public/api/v1/pqr"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Why are u using proxies! Try removing them.

Answer (score 0):

Hey u could try this see if it helps:

Insted of:

`apiUrl = ‘http://localhost:8100/development/abc/public/api/v1/apiName’;`

There must be some port also associated like `8100` is of ionic your api must be running on different port try checking that and making ammendments:

`apiUrl = ‘http://localhost:<some_other_port_number>/development/abc/public/api/v1/apiName’;`

**Another Solution:**

I don't know how u are handling the post data on your server side but still:

Your code:

```
               `let data1 = JSON.stringify({
                    user_id: 14,
                    token: “dsfdsffsfsffsdfffsdffsfs”
                });`
```

Try changing this to just :

```
               `let data1 = {
                    user_id: 14,
                    token: “dsfdsffsfsffsdfffsdffsfs”
                }`
```

What the problem may be you are sending just the string without any label or key:

`this.http.post(this.apiUrl, data1, options)`

So `data1` should go as an `JSON Object` not a `string`

You can try this with or without using proxies as I really don't know how is your client side working.

**Still If the problem persists follow these links:**

[Fixing Connection Refused Error](http://www.incrediblelab.com/fix-err-connection-refused/)

Hope it helps!